# Align struct members but not struct itself

Tags: rust, abi

I'm writing some Rust code that interfaces with C. The C defines some structures like

```c
struct foo {
    // other fields
    uint32_t count;
    const struct bar* array;
};
```

I want to define a Rust structure with this layout, but for safety I want to put `count` and `array` in their own structure as private members, like so:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Foo {
    // other fields
    pub bars: BarSlice,
}
#[repr(C)]
pub struct BarSlice {
    count: u32,
    ptr: *const Bar,
}
```

This is wrong though, since on 64-bit systems BarSlice will be aligned to 8 bytes, and the field immediately before `count` might be 8 byte aligned and 4 bytes long. How can I tell Rust to align the members of the struct correctly, but not worry about the struct itself?

I would also rather avoid if possible

- creating a different slice type for each alignment circumstance
- having private fields in `Foo`

Comment: I don’t think this is served by any existing Rust feature.  There were some discussions in the Rust Internals forum thread [‘Towards even smaller structs’](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/towards-even-smaller-structs/14686) about potential future solutions.

Comment: In my experience, making `#[repr(C)]` types for FFIs should strive to match definitions exactly as they are to avoid confusion and reduce possibility of issues like you mention here, ergonomics come secondary. What you ask for goes against what `#[repr(C)]` is designed to do: match the layout of the equivalent C structure, alignment included. Use a wrapper or intermediary type if you want a different API surface.